# Monotouch Dialog Datepicker and RadioGroup Navigationitem

Tags: dialog, uinavigationitem, monotouch.dialog

I can´t figure out how to correctly design the pushed viewcontrollers navigation back item of a RadioGroup.

So in the follow up screen where the languages are selectable the back Button says "Settings" and is blue. But I want to make it say back and change its design which mechanisms exists and I´m already using in other screens.

I build it up like this:

```
var rootSettings = new RootElement ("Settings");
            var sectionNotificationSettings = new Section ("Notification settings");  

            BooleanElement pushEnabled = new BooleanElement("Push notifications", settings.PushEnabled);
            sectionNotificationSettings.Add(pushEnabled);  

            var sectionCountrySettings = new Section("Country settings");
            var rootRadioGroup = new TransparentRootElement ("Language", new RadioGroup("languages", 0));

            var sectionRadioElements = new Section("");

            foreach(var language in settings.Languages)
            {
                RadioElement selectableLanguage = new RadioElement(language.Key, "languages");
                sectionRadioElements.Add(selectableLanguage);
            }

            rootRadioGroup.Add(sectionRadioElements);

            sectionCountrySettings.Add(rootRadioGroup);

            rootSettings.Add (sectionNotificationSettings);
            rootSettings.Add(sectionCountrySettings);
```

And here I define the TransparentRootElement where I thought I can edit the navigation Item:

```
public class TransparentRootElement : RootElement {

public TransparentRootElement (string caption) : base (caption)
{

}

public TransparentRootElement (string caption, Group radioGroup ) : base (caption, radioGroup)
{

}

public override void Selected (DialogViewController dvc, UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath path)
{       
    base.Selected (dvc, tableView, path, true);
}

void HandleMenuButtonTouchUpInside (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _dvc.NavigationController.PopViewControllerAnimated(true);
}

public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tv)
{
    var cell = base.GetCell (tv);
    //cell.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;

    return cell;
}
}
```

I tried many edit approaches but none of the worked. I also began editing the Elements.cs in Monotouch Dialog but this also did not helped me alot.

Anyone who has a suggestion?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe to change the navigation's back button, you have to hide the default back button and then assign your own.  (Right before you push the new view controller, I believe in your case, it would be before you push the Language screen) Something like this:

```
toPushscreen.NavigationItem.SetHidesBackButton(true, true);
toPushscreen.NavigationItem.LeftBarButtonItem = new UIBarButtonItem("Back", UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, myHandler);
currentScreen.NavigationController.PushViewController(toPushscreen, true);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hello TChadwick,
I´m not pushing the language screen myself. It´s done via the monotouchdialog. I just add a new RootElement with a Radiogroup and sections that get pushed automatically if I tap on the groups rootelement. Internally MonTouchDialog uses push mechanisms wich I´ve found inside the elements.cs but I wouldn´t like to change it in there .

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I haven't had any experience yet with using monotouch dialog, however, I would check to see, if you are using the version of monotouch dialog that came with the last monotouch update, and if so, you may try switching to the latest version on github, or if you are on the version of github, you may switch over to the built in version that came with the last build of monotouch.  Just a few ideas...